# MySQL in python. Insert query does not work

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I have a problem with MySQL's INSERT query.

Here is my python code:

```
import socket
import MySQLdb

    def create_db():
         db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="root")
         cursor = db1.cursor()
         sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  env_data;'
         select_db = 'USE env_data'
         ins = "insert into env_data(cpu_usage, date, mem_usage) values('40%', '1999-01-01 11:11:11', '25%');"
         engine_db = "set sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'"
         us = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS env_data (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,date datetime NOT NULL,cpu_usage varchar(10) NOT NULL,mem_usage varchar(10) NOT NULL);'
         cursor.execute(select_db)
         cursor.execute(us)
         cursor.execute(engine_db)
         cursor.execute(ins)
```

After execution database and tables are created properly, but the insert not works.
When I do this query in my mysql server it works, but from this python script - there are no inserts in cpu_usage, date, mem_usage.

In the script I have also tried to do `mysql_notes = 0 / mysql_notes = 1`.

Could please someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `db1.commit()` after the insert statements. This works in mysql workbench/command line, because, it has an *autocommit* options which is set to *true* by default. Otherwise, you would have to do the same.